# Android SQLite callback after transaction is complete

Tags: android, sqlite, callback, listener

Looking for a solution to a SQLite error I'm encountering in Android.  Basically in some cases I'm running an insert query, then closing the activity I'm in and moving to the next.  Closing the activity entails making sure the SQLiteDatabase is stopped, so onPause in the activity stops the database.

However I'm struggling to make the app wait until the transaction is done.  I see there exists a [SQLiteTransactionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteTransactionListener.html), but its onCommit method is called *before* the commit, leaving open the possibility in my mind that in some cases I end up with the same problem.

How can I get a callback when the transactions are closed so I can delay shutting down the database object?

```
public void insertArrayList(SQLiteDatabase db, String Table, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> tableData, Boolean clear) {
    Logg.d("Start");
    Cursor cols = db.rawQuery("select * from " + Table + " limit 0",null);
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        if (clear) {db.execSQL("delete from " + Table);}
        int Xtra = cols.getColumnCount() - tableData.get(0).size();
        for (ArrayList<String> item : tableData) {
            for (int a=0;a<Xtra;a++) {item.add("");}
            db.execSQL("insert into " + Table + " values " + rowValues(item) + ";");
            //Logg.i("insert into " + Table + " values " + rowValues(item) + ";");
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logg.e("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
        Logg.d("Finish");
    }
}
```

Activity onPause override:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (db != null) {
        Logg.d("SQLite db closing");
        db.close();
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don´t stop the database! Use the same database stored in your custom application class. So it´s open as long as the application is open and close it onTerminate().

Comment: I converted my app to use a SQLiteOpenHelper in a singleton pattern with the SqLiteDatabase object contained within the Helper.

Comment: Great Scott! Remember to close it on application termination.